# Android/iOS OpenCV Eye Dilation Detection

Tags: android, ios, opencv

Looking for opinions on if OpenCV could be or has been used to detect eye dilation on Android or iOS.  I haven't found much other than eye tracking and blink detection with the app EyePhone that uses OpenCV.  Under perfect conditions, I'm sure it's possible, I'm more curious of seeing a proof of concept, that it can and has been done.

Thank you for your opinion.

rd42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try template matching, it gives me best results for now. You can see my sample app:
[Example app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK4zkpjO_3Y) or use haar detector as its at the start of video, but haar detector is slowly and drop fps.

Comment: for what - Android has two ways to acess Opencv - java wrappers or native C? [Template Matching](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) is good C example, java wrappers use the same method, but with little different syntax

Comment: The sample in this video is cool. Can you share any tutorial or sample code?

Comment: Im currently edition the code for tutorial, hope, that will we published soon, I post link here.

Comment: http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/  finally published draft, I will add other tuts later