# Eye tracking in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm looking to do basic eye tracking using an Android tablet, hopefully to track the users eyes to allow movement of a cursor around the screen. I've been doing some searching, I've read a little bit about [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) and [FaceL](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyvision/index.php?title=FaceL:_Facile_Face_Labeling) and have seen an example in another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989451/android-ios-opencv-eye-dilation-detection) showing it is possible to track eye movement on android.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good tutorials or sample code that would be good to refer to or work from? I'm looking for anything that can help me figure how to get this working. Even in its most basic form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found your question via comment.
FaceL use OpenCV too, but with python wrappers.

For basic ideas I recommend this:

- [eye tracking](https://web.archive.org/web/20120130125034/http://nashruddin.com/eyetracking-track-user-eye.html)
- [eye detect](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204225912/http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Eye_Detection)

but they are in native C API (OpenCV 1.X), OpenCV 2.3 java wrappers use C++ API (OpenCV 2.X) syntax, so Mat instead Iplimage etc. 
You can see new syntax in:
[template matching](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

On android you can choose two way to access OpenCV - JAVA API (70% functions) or C++ (with android NDK)

Im using java side and think, all functions you would need are accessible via java side.

Hope that helped you a little ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for following up with my comment, I really appreciate it. Those links look great I'm going to get working with them right away. If you have or find any other code examples anything is appreciated. I'm not the most experienced programmer and this will be a major project for me.

Comment: Start with [Android samples](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidSamples) they are in OpenCV build and try to modify the code and understand using java api like Imgproc.ctvColor() as cvColor() in C++ ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little confused those two basic ideas your gave are using written in C that cant be used on android correct? I have the option between the Java API and using the C++ functions with the android NDK. But the samples in your comment are using the c++ ndk correct? I tried looking for eye tracking examples with the java api but i cant find any... any idea where i could find some?

Comment: You can use C/C++ code with NDK and code from all links too, but with some modifications (JNI call),but Java wrappers have similar syntax as C++ syntax. Android samples use both - first three use java + last one use OpenCV native camera (highgui), next ones use C/C++ or mixed code with Java. So if sample has jni folder, it use native code:) I dont know about any public example with java api (I cant share my code now because its my thesys, sorry), but its simple the same code rewrited to java, look into this [group](https://groups.google.com/group/android-opencv) there are many examples. Roman

Comment: Im starting with some tutorials there: http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/

Answer (score 1):

Try [Opengazer](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/opengazer/). Actually it is used in PC (linux/Mac). But you can get an idea where to start.

Comment: Thanks, even though its not android or Java I'll definitely take a look at the code to get some ideas!